# Android - Deleting database entries using cursor

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm looking to add a new feature to my BETA version of my application.I think I need help on my approach to handling deleting a specific row.

I've been able to do everything I want with the databases in my app except for deleting a particular row or ID value from both database tables.

I'm calling a deleteClient() and passing the cursor in my DBAdapter. This table takes a long value for the rowID.

DBAdapter:

```
public boolean deleteClient(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

DatabaseHandler creates a second database for other storage work but should delete the same:

```
public boolean delete(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(TABLE_LABELS, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

In my class I've tried a few variations on like this:
//db = the databaseadapter

```
db.open();
long loadID = contactList.getSelectedItemId(); 
//contact list is a spinner that is auto populated with each new entry added to it. 
Cursor cursor = db.getClient(loadID);
db.deleteClient(cursor);
db.close();
```

AND THIS

```
dh.getWritableDatabase();
long currentlySelected = contactList.getSelectedItemId();
dh.delete(currentlySelected);
dh.close();
```

One deletes but not the right selection - the other causes an immediate crash. DDMS has given hints but I cant figure out what else could be going on.

Any thoughts on this structure in general or better techniques on this approach?

Spinner loaded like this:

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
        // database handler
        DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());


        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> lables = dbh.getAllLabels();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        contactList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: I don't think your `deleteClient` accepts a cursor.

Comment: Thanks -M-WajeEh. You think I should change it to something like:
public Cursor deleteClient(cursor)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + cursor, null) > 0;
    }

Comment: and how are you populating your `spinner` exactly? Are you sure `contactList.getSelectedItemId()` is returning correct id? Please post the code of your `Adapter`.

Comment: The spinner is populating from the main database that is populated from another activity and calls a loadSpinnerData() that calls from the secondary database thats also written to. It works beautifully but I cant be sure why deleting from that databse is erroring out.

Comment: No man do it like this, `return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID")), null) > 0;` considering you have `_ID` column.

Comment: you sir are the man. Thank you! should I keep the public Boolean aspect or change that also and use this with it?

Comment: keep `public boolean`, btw generally count of deleted rows is returned so you should use `public int deleteClient(cursor) { return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID")), null);}`

Comment: @M-WaJeEh thanks again man I'm going to try this.